# Integral $\Phi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of differential equation $(u' = v(u+v-1), v'=u(1-u-v))$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We have the following system of differential equations:

\begin{equation}
  _{} 
    \begin{cases}
      u' = v(u+v-1)\\
      v' = u(1-u-v) 
       & \text{}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

How can one find out the first integral $\Phi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$? ($\Phi$ shouldn't be a constant)

If I understand it correctly, by an integral of a differential equation is primarily meant a relation of the form $\Phi(x,y) = 0$ defining a solution $y$ of an ordinary differential equation $F(x,y,y'...y(n)) = 0$.

However, I don't get anywhere with this because the differential equation alrady consists of derivatives. I wasn't able to find anything on the internet.

How does one go on about this?

Comment: **HINT**: Did you notice that on an integral curve you must have $$\frac{dv}{du} = -\frac uv?$$

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried integrating both of the equations

Comment: With respect to what? It made no sense. Maybe you should think about my hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
  _{} 
    \begin{cases}
     u u' = u v(u+v-1)\\
     v v' = v u(1-u-v) 
       & \text{}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

and after adding we have
$$
\frac 12(u^2+v^2)' = 0\Rightarrow u^2+v^2 = C_0
$$

Comment: Thank you, but what does that mean for the equilibrium points? How can I calculate them?

Comment: @user10930711 this doesn't tell you anything about the equilibrium points. The only information you obtain from the above response is that any solution $\big(u(t),v(t)\big)$ to this system subject to the initial condition $(u_0,v_0)$ will be contained in the circle $u^2+v^2=u_0^2+v_0^2$. If you want to compute the equilibrium points you need to find all $(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ solving the system of equations $$v(u+v-1)=0$$ $$u(1-u-v)=0$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling
Thank you. So, $v = 2, u = -1$ are the equilibrium points?
Is there a way to get the phase portrait (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_portrait) for this differential equation online?

Comment: The origin is an equilibrium point as well as any point on the line $u+v=1$. If you want to draw a phase portrain by hand (which I highly recommend) try "shading in" regions in the $uv-$plane that satisfy $$u'>0,v'>0$$ $$u'>0,v'<0$$ $$u'<0,v'>0$$ $$u'<0,v'<0$$